# Problem caused due to Retrofit while building release APK

Tags: android, apk

I want to build the release APK. But I am getting errors as shown below.

[image: img2]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have enabled **proguard**.

Either disable it by setting `minifyEnabled false` in your `build.gradle` file, or add the necessary proguard rules for retrofit from [this link.](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro)